# Artificially degrade apache2 performance to meet real world conditions

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, lag, degraded

I want to degrade my apache2 development server performance (it's on a local network) to simulate real world conditions (lag, slow connections, random timeouts...).

Is there any apache mod to do something similar?

Comment: Related question with useful answers: [Simulate delayed and dropped packets on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Run ab (Apache Benchmark), tool provided with most Apache installations. It can simulate heavy load on server. Choose proper one URL to make hits, if your app depends on DB, choose URL connecting DB

More info:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html